# WPML doesn't show language flags only on a single post (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, templates, post, wpml

WPML's language flags display well on pages but not on a single post.
It doesn't show language flags only on a single post that I created using Elementor template.
It even doesn't show a default flag on a single post.

Would you please let me know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You have create custom header using elementor? What is the website link ?

Comment: Hi: Yeah, I created a custom header using elementor, and the language flags display well on all pages. It jsut doesn't display on a single post. The site is under construction. I'm not sure what would be the reason...

Comment: Please add language switcher in header menu from Appearance->menu option so you will get lang. flag along with menu item so it will be visible to all pages